# :: simple-jndi and relative path to config doesn'T work

Tags: java

**My setting:**

***Environment***

- Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS
- Eclipse Helios
- GWT 2.4
- Maven 2
- simple-jndi

***Project***

dialoguemaps-domain *(Java project folder)*

-> src/main/resources/jndi.properties *(simple-jndi configuration)*

-> config/dialoguemaps.properties *(data source configuration)*

**My problem:**

If i use an absolute path in my jndi.properties file - it work's fine:

```
org.osjava.sj.root=/home/arno/.workspaces/dialoguemaps-trunk/dialoguemaps-domain/config/
```

But if i use a relative path it doesn't work:

```
org.osjava.sj.root=config/
```

I have to use an relative path, but how - what is the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that your relative path isn't relative to what you think it is.

You don't show your error message, but it may contain the absolute path that simple-jndi was trying to resolve.

I think that you're going to have to determine what the absolute path really is, and configure that.

Answer (score 0):

I know its 7 years past since the question is asked but I'm gonna answer it because I also had problem with configuration similar like yours. The best way to deal it it is to put a "." (dot) before "config". Something like:

```
org.osjava.sj.root=./config/
```

Console would alert you that it was unable to load class and then would write a path that it tried to load class something like:

```
[ERROR] ... Unable to load: C:\Users\name.surname\Desktop\appdirectory1\appdirectory2\appdirectory3\.\config
```

Then you just have to put a directories that are missing. For example I put:

```
#org.osjava.sj.root=./src/main/resources
```

and it works just fine.